# Charts don't plot if using values below 1 second

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I am extremely new to Grafana, I am using Grafana v4.1.1, influxdb 1.2 and have a range of charts showing my data :)

If I change my __interval from 1s to 100ms, nothing plots on the charts.  I can hover over and it has values at ever one second though?

[image]

I have also added the table view and cannot get milliseconds to display (tried ss.sss, ms etc).  I know the data has them as viewing the date as a string displays as below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there are lots of null values in your serie.

Change `fill(null)` to `fill(none)` or set `Display -> Stacking & null values -> Null value` to `connected` then Grafana will connect the value you have and skip null values.
[image]

Comment: Brilliant, how you worked that out is epic.  Only 1 question, I have 10ms data, which I can view by the table above,  Why is Grafana not plotting it?  only per second one?